# Q&A Database design suggestion in MSSQL/MYSQL

Tags: database

## Detail

I am trying to design a database where each question has multiple option (answer) and when I select the answer it show the the next question related to that answer ans so on with others. It is a tree structure. I am trying it to use in mysql and MSSQL Server. Path of tree vary according to the selected answers dynamically. Best real life reference to this question [Urbanclap](http://www.urbanclap.com)

## Example

```
Question
- Answer 1
   - Question 2
       -Answer 1_Q2
       -Answer 2_Q2
       -Answer 3_Q2

-Question 3
   -Answer 4_Q3
   -Answer 5
   -Answer 6
-Question 4
       -Answer 2
       -Answer 3
       -Answer 4
       -Answer 5
       -Answer 6
```

here is the sample which I want to design
[Sample Schema Response](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb341494)

Comment: So, whats the question? What are your attempts? Relation databases, multiple tables with join statements.

Comment: Yes, a hierarchical design might for you.  Each answer would have a column pointing to another question.  But what is _your_ question?

Comment: Can different questions have different answers link to subsequent questions. I.e. Question 1--> Answer 1 ---> Question 2 , Quesdifferent tion 1 --->Answer 2 ---> Question3

Comment: I edit the question urbanclap did the same

Comment: @RehanAzher yes

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will do :

```
-- Questions Table 
create table qeustions (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- Unique ID for Question
QUESTIONTEXT VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
)

create table ANSWERS (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   -- Unique ID for Answer
QUESTIONID UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- Answer belongs to which question
ANSWERTEXT VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,  -- text of answer
RELATEDID UNSIGNED    -- if have related question insert id here
)
```

Below is Valid MYSQL create statements:

```
create table qeustions (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
QUESTIONTEXT VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

create table ANSWERS (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
QUESTIONID INT NOT NULL,
ANSWERTEXT VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
RELATEDID INT 
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06c1d5